# Create a drop-down menu with Tumblr theme meta-if tags?

Tags: tumblr, meta-tags

Is it possible to create a drop-down menu in the Tumblr theme appearance options using meta-if tags/booleans, like you can for the meta-font tags? For example, in the theme I'm working on, I have different numbers of columns meta-if options. My HTML for that looks like this:

```
<meta name="if:1 Column" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:2 Columns" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:3 Columns" content="1"/>
```

and the CSS like this:

```
{block:If1Column} 1 Column css here {/block:If1Column}
{block:If2Columns} 2 Columns css here {/block:If2Columns}
{block:If3Columns} 3 Columns css here {/block:If3Columns}
```

In the appearance options, "1 Column," "2 Columns," and "3 Columns" show up as options with a checkbox next to them. But the problem is, if you check more than one of them, or none of them, the theme gets all messed up. So I was wondering if there's any way I could replace the checkboxes with a drop-down menu, like with fonts, or somehow make it so you can only choose one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now (kinda) possible.

The meta tags look like this:

```
<meta name="select:Columns" title="2" content="two-col" />
<meta name="select:Columns" title="3" content="three-col" />
```

And then you can use `{select:Columns}` wherever you want and it will be replaced with the content of the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it’s possible. According to the Custom Theme documentation, only the following [Appearance Options](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#appearance-options) are available:

- Enabling Custom Colors
- Enabling Custom Fonts
- Enabling Booleans
- Enabling Custom Text
- Enabling Custom Images
- Enabling Custom CSS

Where only "Booleans" or "Custom Text" would be possible for your case (Booleans preferred, of course).

However, I think your case should be possible without needing such a select list. If you make clever use of the cascade, users could enable any combination of column checkboxes without messing up your theme. E.g. default to a 1 column layout. If the checkbox "2 columns" is enabled, don’t remove the 1 column layout CSS, overwrite it instead. If the checkbox "3 columns" is enabled, don’t remove the CSS for 1 and 2 columns but overwrite it again. So users could activate both checkboxes, but only the CSS for the "highest" one would be applied.

Comment: It's possible now, they added a new subsection "Enabling drop-down lists."